# Fan does not work on Dell XPS 13 developer edition with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, fan

After updating my Dell XPS 13 developer edition to Ubuntu 14.04 the fan is not working. The `i8kutils` are installed but `i8kmon` does not work. 
It returns

```
* starting Dell fan/cpu-temperature monitor i8kmon   [fail]
```